# More pseudo-diminutives like “Eichhörnchen”?

Tags: etymology, diminutive

The [German Wikipedia article on diminutive](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutiv#Verselbst.C3.A4ndigte_Diminutive) features a section on “Verselbständigte Diminutive”. These words all have conventional meaning, i.e. they are listed in a dictionary by themselves and not as part of their stem entry. Some of the stems are uncommon (today), e.g. *Mär* and *Maid/Magd* hence the derivation is intransparent for many people. Many are compounds that denote plants and animals where neither the left nor the right-hand part would denote one and only few could also be used without *-chen*, e.g. *Meerschwein, Seepferd, Silberfisch* are not unheard of. One can use the semantic opaqueness to construct bad puns, e.g. “Die neue Frau meines Vaters ist recht klein, ein richtiges *Stiefmütterchen*.”

I’m interested in the last category, words that look like diminutives but aren’t. *Eichhörnchen* ‘squirrel’ doesn’t derive from *Horn* and *Plätzchen* ‘cookie’ doesn’t derive from *Platz*, although words like *Ruheplätzchen* do. (I think *Veilchen* may be misplaced there, because *Veil* is not a German word.) Are there any more like these?

There probably needs to be a consonant preceding *-chen*, since some (orthographic) candidates are nowhere near being thought of as a diminutive, e.g. nouns *Knochen, Zeichen, Rachen, Drachen, Rochen, Sachen* and several verbs used as nouns like *Kochen, Suchen, Erwachen, Lachen, Sprechen, Tauchen, Stechen* and, of course, *Catchen*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Es ist nicht so einfach, eine Frage zu beantworten, die auf falschen Voraussetzungen beruht.

**Eichhörnchen** *ist* ein Diminutiv, allerdings nicht von *Horn*, sondern von *Eichhorn*, das vom mittelhochdeutschen *eichorn* (in etwa: flinkes Tier) abstammt, welches ein nicht-zusammengesetztes Wort war. Erst später wurde es als solches wahrgenommen, weshalb dann das *Eichhörn-chen* als *Eich-hörnchen* aufgefasst wurde. Daraus abgeleitet wurde dann der Name der Nagetierfamilie *Hörnchen* und mehrerer Vertreter dieser Familie. Wenn Du so willst, fallen diese also in die von Dir beschriebene Kategorie, das Eichhörnchen selbst aber nicht. Quelle: [Wikipedia](http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6rnchen#Etymologie), [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GE00970#XGE00970)

Hinsichtlich **Platz** ist die Wikipedia in sich widersprüchlich, denn der von Dir angeführte Artikel verlinkt auf https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%A4tzchen, wo das Wort als Diminutiv zu dem heute (in dieser Bedeutung) nicht mehr gebräuchlichen [Platz](http://www.dwds.de/?kompakt=1&qu=Platz) geführt wird (frühnhd. plazc oder blacz).

Ähnlich verhält es sich mit **Veilchen**. Zumindest laut [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV00188#XGV00188) war *Veil*, abgeleitet vom lat. *viola*, vor langer Zeit als Name für die Blume (und einige als verwandt angesehene Pflanzen) in Gebrauch. Heute hat der Diminutiv das Stammwort komplett verdrängt.

Soweit zur Bestandsaufnahme. Falls es Dir einfach um Wörter geht, die zwar ein Diminutiv sind, aber nicht zu einem heute noch (in äquivalenter Bedeutung) gebräuchlichen Wort, hätte ich anzubieten:

- [Stövchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stoevchen), eine Vorrichtung zum Warmhalten von Tee und anderen Getränken, deren Name auf *stove* zurückgeht, was eigentlich "beheizte Badestube" bedeutet.
- [Motschekiebchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Motschekiebchen), eine "ostmitteldeutsche" (für mich schlicht: sächsische) Bezeichnung für Marienkäfer, über [Motschekühchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Motschekuehchen) abgeleitet von *Muhkuh*.
- [Mätzchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Maetzchen) (machen), das laut Duden zwar auf [Matz](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Matz) zurückgeht, aber in der heute nicht mehr gebräuchlichen Bedeutung »dummer, törichter Kerl«
- und eventuell [Bäuerchen](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/B%C3%A4uerchen) in der Bedeutung "Rülpsen beim Baby", das zwar meist auf den Bauer und dessen ungehobelte Sitten zurückgeführt wird, was man aber zumindest bei Wiktionary für zweifelhaft genug erachtet, um die Herkunft als "ungeklärt" einzuordnen

Und dann ist da noch das [Schmeckerchen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Schmeckerchen), über dessen Herleitung ich bislang nichts in Erfahrung bringen konnte.

Comment: I answered in German for lack fo time and because I assume the OP understands it. If anybody feels like translating the answer to make that thread consistenly use English: please do (although I think this question could have been written in German from the start).

Answer (score 4):

Veilchen kommt vom lateinischen Viola, und das Wort "Veil" gab es tatsächlich, ist aber ausgestorben. Auch das Eichorn (nicht "Eichhorn"!) bzw. Ekhorn gab es mal. Ein Platz war mal nicht nur eine frei Fläche, sondern auch ein Teigfladen (pfannkuchenartig, Fladenbrot usw.) Daher sind Veilchen, Eichhörnchen und Plätzchen tatsächlich echte Diminutive, deren "große" Form ausgestorben ist.

Andere Diminutive, deren große Form existiert hat, aber ausgestorben ist, sind das Kaninchen und das Frettchen.

Das mit dem Konsonanten stimmt auch nicht: Das "Frauchen" geht mit ihrem Hündchen Gassi. Ich habe keine große Idee, sondern nur ein kleines "Ideechen".

Es gibt nun mal wenige Substantive, die mit einem Vokal enden, und falls doch, ist es meist ein e, und das verschwindet aber wenn ein Diminutiv gebildet wird: Gruppe - Grüppchen, Geschichte - Geschichtchen, Stunde - Stündchen.

Comment: Versuche deine Antworten in derselben Sprache zu geben, in der die Frage gestellt wurde. Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/830/1487

Comment: ok danke, war mir nicht klar, aber macht Sinn.

Answer (score 0):

I have just looked at Eichhörnchen in DWDS. They have an older form Eichhorn, so that Eichhörnchen is a diminutive form. The two parts Eich- and Horn/Hörnchen seem mysterious as the small delicate animals have no horn, and they have no special preference for oaks. The etymological dictionary of Pfeifer, which is part of DWDS, can't explain these two parts. The assumption is that both parts are  words that were later transformed to Eich- and Horn/Hörnchen.

http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Eichh%C3%B6rnchen

Comment: Even if you could assert the existence of _Eichhorn_, it fails for all other _Hörnchen_ like _*Streifenhorn_ and _*Flughorn_. Also, this doesn’t really answer my question.

Comment: @Crissov Roger is right about _Eichhorn_. See http://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6rnchen#Etymologie for the other _Hörnchen_.

Answer (score 0):

In my bakery round the corner they used to offer a "Bismarck Platz" - meaning a big Bismarck "Plätzchen". However, I do not think you'll find the word "Platz" in today's bakery books.

Answer (score 0):

The Eichhörnchen is the closest we have to a so-called *egghorn* (read: acorn, compare *Eichel*; after a languagelog blog posting). Since it does not contrast with any Horn on pragmatic grounds, it is strictly speaking not a diminutive. Animals with hand-like paws tend to be antropomorphized more easily, eg. *Wasch-Bär(chen?)*, and the miniature size of it is readly contrasted with more intimidating animals, eg. *Bär* / *Wunderbärchies*. So, the diminutive is fully warranted on underlying lexical grounds, but the stem is a cranberry morpheme (like *crane-*) and *hörn actually is not a morpheme at all, so *eichhörn-* is monomorphemic *mutatis mutandis*. That might make it a pseudo-diminutive in an etymological sense.

The quest as per OP is to show that this extensive definition generalizes over a compact set in the lexicon. This can be made stratified in the ideal case that evidence has been dated, eg. from loan words. The *Küch'lein* might belong here if you accept *-ch-* as a contracted affix, cp. En. *cooky* (from Dutch). Albeit, the etymology of *Kuchen* is remarkably uncertain. This is incident to *Plätzchen*, which is a loan into high High German, but you can also find *Printen*. A wide range of *pane* words remains ultimately unsolved, e.g. *pizza*. Cp. *Flammkuchen*. Bread backing is old, but not stone old in the former pastoral communities. So, this is an unriable data-point.

*k develops to German *h*, French *ch* (Hund, chien, Latin *canis* /k/) if from Germanic, but *c* /ts/ from some layer of Latin, *Dezember, Decembre*, as well as from *t (sweetheart, Süße, Herzilein). So it could be either from *plat- (as is prefered) or from *plak- (cp. *Flammkuchen*, *Flach, Fläche(n)*) with a more or less phonetically conditioned Reibelaut. It bears mention that *Platt schnacken* corresponds to *Snack naschen* (not to toot my own horn), cp. En. *fnaese* "sneeze" for the sound change.

The *Knöllchen* "citation" is notable as well. Although it could to mean *knüllen*, and *Knolle* may be the etymological root (eg. root bunch, bunch up), it works on a rather sound-symbolic level. It is remarkable that *kn-* covers a wide range of Lautmalerei, some of which connecers to terms like *Knecht*, *Knabe*, etc. that may be frequent in appellative.

After all, cp. En. *-kin*, which is the most likely exponent of the same root in the geneological tree. The tree is broad enough to allow some *overloaded* morphemes. Eg., a prosodic stop would be allowable before *ch* because underlying vowels condition its contrastive distribution /x ç/, and a (glottal) stop is allowable before vowel initial syllables. If this stop may appear between the preceeding stops onset and release because the apex is tenuis, then *'tchen* is allomorph to *-chen* and the n-stem may be explained via Kroonen on Kluge's law as indicated by the geminate. See also Dutch *plantjes*, cp. Irish *clan*.